# DBCC CHECKDB REPAIR_REBUILD taking too long

Tags: sql-server-2008, corruption

I'm administrating a database that became corrupt and I tried to do a `REPAIR_REBUILD`.

The server on this installation is a bit weak but the database isn't that big (roughly 2GB).

It's been running for 48 hours and still not completed. Is it possible ? And is there any way to check the current state other than just seeing "Executing query" ?

Comment: How many indexes was corrupted? 48 hours seem exagerated as in 48 hours it's possible to rebuild all non-clustered indexes of 2Gb database

Answer (score 2):

You could always run the following script to check the running tasks:

```
SELECT 
    start_time,
    DATEADD(ms,estimated_completion_time,GETDATE()) AS 'EstimatedEndTime',
    percent_complete,
    --sqltext.TEXT, 
    req.session_id, 
    req.status, 
    req.command, 
    req.cpu_time, 
    req.total_elapsed_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests req 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(req.sql_handle) 
where req.command like '%DBCC%'
```

Comment out the `sqltext.TEXT` column if you wish to view the whole statement.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query (change session_id for your own that executed the command):

```
select session_id, command, percent_complete

from sys.dm_exec_requests

where session_id=55
```

Comment: Why session_id=55;

Comment: it was just an example. Read the full text. I said to replace session_id for the one he executed the command.

Comment: @hot2use - Wouldn't that give you the % complete of this script, not of the connection running the `CHECKDB`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes , you can check the current status of the DBCC Checkdb.

- Run sp_who2 and identify the spid which is running the DBCC CHECKDB
- Once you have the SPID, use it to identify the % with below query:

> Select session_id, command, percent_complete  from sys.dm_exec_requests
>   where session_id= Your_SPID